# USB modem cannot be recognized via USB extension cord

Tags: windows-7, usb

I am trying to connect my USB modem through a USB extension cord ~5m, but the thing is my computer can't seem to recognize the USB. The power indicator in the modem says it has power, but the computer still won't recognize it. The extension cord is working OK, then all of a sudden it is not. Any help?

Comment: The maximum length for a USB extension cable is 5 meters.  If you're having problems of any kind, then you really should be using an **active** extension cable.

Comment: Or a shorter USB cable. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a power problem. The wires in the cable have electrical resistance which will make the voltage decrease proportionally with the power use of the device. Normally, this is voltage drop is negligible, for a typical cable and power use, but can become a problem for long cables and high power devices. (The USB modem is a radio transmitter which is high power by USB standards.)

I would suggest getting a USB hub that is powered from an adapter that you place on the other side of the cable. This might help, but no guarantees.